# Many-to-many relationships in ASP.NET Dynamic Data

Tags: asp.net, many-to-many, dynamic-data

I need to use a many to many relationship in my project and since Dynamic Data doesn't support it natively, I would like to ask for a sample of an implementation of something like it.

I'm specifically looking for a way to both create new instances of the target entity and add a new m2m relationship to a record as well as using existing instances to create the relationship.

I'm on a tight schedule, so any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David Ebbo (the architect for Dynamic Data) posted a [Many-to-Many field template](http://blogs.msdn.com/davidebb/archive/2008/10/25/a-many-to-many-field-template-for-dynamic-data.aspx) on his blog. Note that this solution is specifically for Entity Framework.